# Variable not getting reassign after encountering a conditional statements in

Tags: javascript, css

Variable sliding_index getting not reassign after code goes through the if statement.

I was trying to make a slider function that can trigger whenever an user clicked the button but it goes to fail when it face the if statement, if statement to call the function with the initial value( sliding_index Start from 1 ) or with the last value(array length).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Takshila VidyaPeeth</title>

    <style>

        *{

            margin: 0;

            padding: 0;

        }

        .main-menu-container{

            display:grid;

            grid-template-columns:10vw 80vw;

            justify-content:space-between;

            align-items:center;

            box-sizing:border-box;

        }

        .main-sub-menu-container{

            display:flex;

            flex-direction:row;

            justify-content:space-between; 

            align-items:center;

            box-sizing:border-box;

            padding:0 0 0 373px;

        }

        .main-sub-menu-container li{

            list-style:none;

        }

        .main-sub-menu-container li a{

            text-decoration:none;

        }

        .center{

            width:70vw;

            margin:0 auto;

            padding:10px 0;

        }

        .sub-menu-container{

            display:flex;

            flex-direction:row;

            justify-content:space-between;

            align-items:center;

            box-sizing:border-box;

            padding:0 200px;

        }

        .sub-menu-container li{

            list-style:none;

        }

        .sub-menu-container li a{

            text-decoration:none;

        }

        .sliding-image-div{

            display:flex;

            flex-direction:row;

            justify-content:space-between;

            align-items:center;

            width:100vw;

            height: 40vh;

            border:1px solid red;

            box-sizing:border-box;

            padding:0 30px;

        }

        .sliding-image-div img{

            width:40vw;

            height: 40vh;

            display:none;

        }

        .result-sliding-image{

margin:0;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <section>

    <div class="main-menu-container">

        <div class="logo"><img src="myself.jpeg" alt="logo failed" width=70px height=70px style="border-radius:50%"><span style="display:block">Takshila VidyaPeeth</span></div>

        <div>

            <ul class="main-sub-menu-container">

                <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="About US.php">About us</a></li>

                <li><a href="contact US.php">Contact Us</a></li>

                <li><a href="https://www.google.com/maps">Select City</a></li>

                <li><a href="welcome.php">Payment</a></li>

                <li><a href="login.php" target="_blank">Login</a></li>

                <li><form action="" method="GET"><select name="search here" id="search here"><option value="">Search here...</option><option value="Maths">Maths</option><option value="English">English</option><option value="Science">Science</option></select></form></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    </section>

    <section>

        <div class="center">

            <ul class="sub-menu-container">

                <li><a href="branches.php">center</a></li>

                <li><a href="courses.php">Courses</a></li>

                <li><a href="result.php">Result</a></li>

                <li><a href="Query.php">Query</a></li>

                <li><a href="library.php">Library</a></li>

                <li><a href="feedback.php" target="_blank">feedback</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </section>

    <section>

        <div class="sliding-image-div" id="sliding-image-div">

            <p style="display:inline-block;" onclick="Minus_slider(-1)"> &lt; </p>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="1" class="result_sliding_image" id=1>

            <img src="" alt="2" class="result_sliding_image" id=2>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="3" class="result_sliding_image" id=3>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="4" class="result_sliding_image" id=4>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="5" class="result_sliding_image" id=5>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="6" class="result_sliding_image" id=6>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="7" class="result_sliding_image" id=7>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="8" class="result_sliding_image" id=8>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="9" class="result_sliding_image" id=9>

            <img src="myself.jpeg" alt="10" class="result_sliding_image" id=10>

            <p style="display:inline-block;" onclick="Plus_slider(1)"> &gt; </p>

        </div>

    </section>

    <script>

        var sliding_index=1;

        slider(sliding_index);

        function Plus_slider

        {

            slider(sliding_index+=n);

        }

        function Minus_slider

        {

            slider(sliding_index+=n);

        }

        function slider(sliding_index)

        {

            var div_id=document.getElementsByClassName("result_sliding_image");

            var lengthh=div_id.length;

            if(sliding_index > lengthh)

            { 

                sliding_index=1;             

            }

            if(sliding_index < 1)

            {

                sliding_index = lengthh;

            }

            var show=document.getElementById(sliding_index);

            console.log(show);

            for(var i=0; i<10; i++)

            {

                div_id[i].style.display="none";

            }

            show.style.display="block";

        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're **shadowing** your global variable with a local variable (well, parameter) with the same name. That means assignments to the parameter just change the parameter, not the global variable. (Also note that when you do `slider(sliding_index)`, you're passing the **value** of `sliding_index`, not some kind of reference to the variable, into the function. JavaScript is purely pass by value.) If you want to update `sliding_index`, then: 1. Don't pass it into `slider`, and 2. Don't declare a `sliding_index` parameter on `slider`. Then `slider` will use and update the global.

Comment: Also, the first index should be 0, not 1.